# Reading from a StdoutPipe() in Go freezes

Tags: go, stdout

I am trying to read from the Stdout of a command, but once every (approx.) 50 times it freezes.

```
func runProcess(process *exec.Cmd) (string, string, error) {
    var stdout strings.Builder
    var stderr string
    process := exec.Command(programPath, params...)

    go func() {
        pipe, err := process.StderrPipe()
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        buf, err := io.ReadAll(pipe)
        if err != nil {
            log.Warn("Error reading stderr: %v", err)
        }
        stderr = string(buf)
    }()

    pipe, err := process.StdoutPipe()
    if err = process.Start(); err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    read, err := pipe.Read(buf)            // it reads correctly from the pipe
    for err == nil && read > 0 {
        _, err = stdout.Write(buf[:read])
        read, err = pipe.Read(buf)         // this is where is stalls
    }
    if err = process.Wait(); err != nil {
        return stdout.String(), stderr, err
    }

    return stdout.String(), stderr, nil
}
```

I've tried to use `stdout, err := io.ReadAll(pipe)` to read everything at once instead of reading chunks, but I get the same behaviour.
The program that is called seems to be executed successfully. Its logfile is created and it is complete. Plus, first time when I read from the pipe (before the loop), all the output is there. But inside the loop, when the `.Read()` is called for the second time and it should return an EOF (the output is smaller than 1024 bytes), it freezes.

Comment: When it freezes, send it a `SIGQUIT`. This will kill the process with a stack trace of all running goroutines, so you can see where it's hung.

Comment: @Adrian: If it's blocked on `Read()`, it would be explained by a leaked pipe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many race conditions in this code. In general, if you create a goroutine, there should be some kind of synchronization--like a `chan`, `sync.Mutex`, `sync.WaitGroup`, or atomic.

Fix the race conditions.

1. Call `StderrPipe()` before calling `Start()`. The code does not do this.
2. Wait for the goroutine to finish before returning.

The race condition could corrupt the `exec.Cmd` structure... which could mean that it leaks a pipe, which would explain why `Read()` hangs (because a write end of the pipe wasn't closed).

As a rule of thumb, **always fix race conditions.** Consider them to be high-priority bugs.

Here is a sketch of how you could write it without race conditions:

```golang
func runProcess(process *exec.Cmd) (stdout, stderr string, err error) {
    outPipe, err := process.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    // Call StderrPipe BEFORE Start().
    // Easy way to do it: outside the goroutine.
    errPipe, err := process.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    // Start process.
    if err := process.Start(); err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    // Read stderr in goroutine.
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var stderrErr error
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(errPipe)
        if err != nil {
            stderrErr = err
        } else {
            stderr = string(data)
        }
    }()

    // Read stdout in main thread.
    data, stdoutErr := ioutil.ReadAll(outPipe)

    // Wait until we are done reading stderr.
    wg.Wait()

    // Wait for process to finish.
    if err := process.Wait(); err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    // Handle error from reading stdout.
    if stdoutErr != nil {
        return "", "", stderrErr
    }
    // Handle error from reading stderr.
    if stderrErr != nil {
        return "", "", stderrErr
    }

    stdout = string(data)
    return stdout, stderr, nil
}
```

### Much Simpler Code

All of this is done by the `os/exec` package automatically. You can use any `io.Writer` for `Stdout` and `Stderr`, you are not limited to `*os.File`.

```golang
func runProcess(process *exec.Cmd) (stdout, stderr string, err error) {
    var stdoutbuf, stderrbuf bytes.Buffer
    process.Stdout = &stdoutbuf
    process.Stderr = &stderrbuf
    if err := process.Run(); err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }
    return stdoutbuf.String(), stderrbuf.String(), nil
}
```

Comment: Brilliant response!

Comment: Why is it necessary to start reading the pipes after calling `Start()`?

Comment: It is okay to read it before it is connected. The read will block.

Comment: It’s not safer. This is not about practical considerations… a pipe is an IPC mechanism like a `chan`. There is no need to wait until a writer is running before you read from a chan, and pipes work the same way.

Comment: The long version of the code works in my case. There is more code in the for loop I have in my example (that's why I need to use `outPipe.Read()` and not `ioutil.ReadAll(outPipe)`. 
The problem was indeed with creating the errPipe inside the goroutine.